# Why is my cache manifest still not working?

Tags: html, offline, html5-appcache, application-cache

I watch in chorme's console,there is nothing output,and no application cache
    why is this happen?thanks

[image: it supported in my server]

and here is my html:

```
<html manifest="http://www.test.com/test.manifest">
```

here is the content of test.manifest file:

```
CACHE MANIFEST       
# VERSION v1.0.120927-1430
CACHE:
http://www.test.info/js/smiles.js
# pic
http://www.test.info/imgs/user_32.gif
http://www.test.info/imgs/user_48.gif
http://www.test.info/smiles/christree.gif
http://www.test.info/smiles/horse2.gif
NETWORK: 
*
```

that is my js code to print the logs:

```
function logEvent(a) {
    console.log(a.type);
    if (a.type == "updateready" || a.type == "cached") {
        applicationCache.swapCache();
    }
    if (a.lengthComputable) {
        console.log("total:" + a.total + "  loaded:" + a.loaded);
    }
    if (a.type == "error") {
        applicationCache.update();
    }
}
if(window.applicationCache){
    window.applicationCache.addEventListener("checking", logEvent, false);
    window.applicationCache.addEventListener("noupdate", logEvent, false);
    window.applicationCache.addEventListener("progress", logEvent, false);
    window.applicationCache.addEventListener("downloading", logEvent, false);
    window.applicationCache.addEventListener("cached", logEvent, false);
    window.applicationCache.addEventListener("updateready", logEvent, false);
    window.applicationCache.addEventListener("obsolete", logEvent, false);
    window.applicationCache.addEventListener("error", logEvent, false);
}
```

I watch in chorme's console,there is nothing output,and no application cache
    why is this happen?thanks

Comment: localStorage and Offline web applications using a cache manifest are 2 very diffrent things!

Answer (score 3):

Your screenshots shows `www.mmbang.com`, but your HTML and manifest relates to `www.test.com`. If that's your original configuration this would never work because the manifest has to have the same origin as the website.